# Comparing Vectors of Different Length

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compare two vectors of different size. For instance when I run the code below:

```
A = [1 4 3 7 9];
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];

myPadded = [A zeros(1,4)];

C = ismember(myPadded,B)
```

I get the following output:

```
C = 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

However, I want an output that will reflect the positions of the compared values, hence, I would like an output that is displayed as follows:

```
C = 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Please, I need some help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 points. First, you are writing the inputs of `ismember` in the wrong order. Additionally, you do not need to grow your matrix. Simply try `ismember(B, A)` and you will get what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

The function `ismember(myPadded, B)` returns a vector the same size of `myPadded`, indicating if the i-th element of myPadded is present in B.

To get what you want, just invert parameter order: `ismember(B, myPadded)`.

Comment: Someone have made a terrible mistake here. This is completely reverse intuitive. Ice cream to all who have never got this comparison reversed :)

Comment: I particularly don't feel that. Rather arbitrary instead. However, it is as simple as writing "help ismember" in the console :-)

Comment: I was about to comment that you only need `ismember(B,A)`, but @erfan posted their answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing this is to use logical indexing. This will only work if the last digit of `B` is included in `A`.

```
A = [1 4 3 7 9];
c(A) = 1; % or true.
```

An assumption here is that you want to subindex a vector 1:N, so that `B` always is `B = 1:N`. In case the last digit is not one this is easy to fix. Just remember to return all to its previous state after you are done. It will be 2 rows extra though.

This solution is meant as a special case working on a very common problem.